# Why is deep plucking a bad idea?

Tags: javascript, array, object

Both [underscore](https://github.com/jashkenas/underscore/issues/712) and [lodash](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/issues/262) refuse to implement deep plucking, despite many requests from users and gists or [modules](https://github.com/mohsen1/deep_pick) that implement the feature.

```
_([{o:{a:1}},{o:{a:43}},{o:{a:234}},{o:{a:23}}]).pluck("o.a")
```

Why is deep plucking a bad idea?

Comment: What the heck is "deep plucking"?  And how is it different from the property chaining implicit in JSON and bog-standard JavaScript?

Comment: [Nope, we don't want to stray into "string programming". Instead, use map, or a more robust syntax like JSONPath.](https://github.com/jashkenas/underscore/issues/712)

Comment: I wonder why no one proposed simply using an array of property names like `_.pluck(..., ['a', 'o'])`, instead of a string in some questionable path format that needs parsing.

Comment: @Ixrec: XPath works similarly for XML.

Comment: underscore-contrib includes `_.getPath` that will accept an array of property names and a JSONPath string: http://documentcloud.github.io/underscore-contrib/#getpath